# How to get an oracle check constraint working with a foreign constraint in a create table statment?

Tags: oracle

When I add a foreign constraint, my check constraint doesn't work, please help?

```
CREATE TABLE cteam_OrgUnit (    
OrgNo NUMBER NOT NULL,   
OrgName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,   
OrgParentNO NUMBER ,
CONSTRAINT cteam_OrgUnit_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrgNo)
);


CREATE TABLE cteam_Users(
    UserNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
    UserFirstName  VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    UserLastName  VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    UserPhone VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    UserEmail varchar2(255) **check (
    UserEmail LIKE '%@%.%' AND UserEmail NOT LIKE '@%' AND UserEmail NOT LIKE '%@%@%'   )**,
    UserOrgNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cteam_Users_PK PRIMARY KEY (UserNo),
    **CONSTRAINT FK_cteam_OrgUnit FOREIGN KEY (UserOrgNo) references cteam_OrgUnit(OrgNo)**
    );


INSERT INTO cteam_OrgUnit 
    (OrgNo, OrgName, OrgParentNo)
    VALUES (1,'Accounting', NULL );



INSERT INTO cteam_Users
    (UserNo, UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserPhone, UserEmail, UserOrgNo)
    VALUES (1,'Sue','Herdon','(206) 339-3312','sherdon@org.com',3);
```

When I try enter "sherdon@org.com" a constraint error is occurring only when the foreign constraint is added!

Comment: It works as it should without the foreign constraint!

Comment: Well, there is no record with `OrgNo = 3` in `cteam_OrgUnit`. The foreign key constraint works as it's supposed to work if it throws an error here.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cfd0115664a17eab56e508567db3d243), the last insert fails with error:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FIDDLE_TUKTBGEGPXLGWTYOKODV.FK_CTEAM_ORGUNIT) violated - parent key not found

You are trying to insert value `3` in column `cteam_Users(UserOrgNo)` while this value does not exists in referenced column `cteam_OrgUnit(OrgNo)` (this table contains a unique record, whose column `OrgNo` has value `1`). The foreign key constraint does not allow that.

Either create a record with value `3` in column `UserOrgNo` in table `cteam_OrgUnit`, or use value `1` when inserting in dependant table `cteam_Users`.